# Git: "warning: ignoring broken ref refs/remotes/origin/master bad revision 'refs/remotes/origin/master..HEAD'

Tags: git, github, git-push

I've been using git without any trouble. However, sometime ago I started to see this message when pushing the commits:

```
warning: ignoring broken ref refs/remotes/origin/master bad revision 'refs/remotes/origin/master..HEAD
```

[(screenshot of the message above)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2U8V.png)

I've saw people saying to point the remote head branch again with :

```
git remote set-head origin master
```

But this returns to me:

```
error: Not a valid ref: refs/remotes/origin/master
```

The problem has to do with the remote branch. Once the command

```
git branch -r
```

outputs me:

```
warning: ignoring broken ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
warning: ignoring broken ref refs/remotes/origin/master
```

So, how to fix it? (**Note**: I still can push the commits correctly.)

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution:

The push has became impossible due to those reference errors. So, I got into the git folder inside my project at `my-project\.git\refs\remotes\origin` and deleted all the remote branchs there.
Then I `git pull` and the remote reference was created again.

After that git told me to set the upstream again using `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master` and to `git pull` one more time so that the problem was solved.